# I'm working with streaming app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, flutter-dependencies, desktop, flutter-test

Is there any package which supports video player of desktop version of flutter? Because according to documentation the existing popular package https://pub.dev/packages/video_player
doesn't support desktop apps ...

Answer (score 0):

The earlier, there was not available any lib but right now a couple of players in the market you can get use it

[Gstremer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gstreamer_player)

[VLC](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_vlc)